# Algolia synonym results not reflecting in the website

Tags: javascript, api, algolia, synonym

I have created a list of synonyms in Algolia, the results of which are showing up in the browse section of the dashboard, but not reflecting in the website; despite other features working fine. Does the API require any additional set of codes to be inserted in the website for such features?

Comment: Can you provide a link to reproducible test case, either your website or a jsFiddle?

Comment: https://onetact.com